# Why is each MenuItem in my react-contextmenu list identical?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contextmenu

For reference, I'm using [react-contextmenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contextmenu) to add context menues to my app.
I have items in a list, and you can right-click each item to do some actions with it. Each item provides a context menu that is also a list, so I have a couple of `map` methods in my code. (I made sure to use unique keys as per the info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and [here](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)). However, this is the behavior I'm observing (right-clicking any item in the list *always* shows me the context menu for the last item in the list):

[image]

Here's my code:

```
function ListItem(props) { 
  // console.log(`CONTEXT OPTIONS for ${props.name}:\n${JSON.stringify(props.contextOptions)}`);

  // console.log(`Mapped context options for ${props.name}:\n${props.contextOptions.map((option) => option.label + option.subLabel)}`);

  const contextOptions = props.contextOptions.map((option) => 
    <MenuItem 
      key={option.label + option.subLabel} 
      disabled={option.disabled} 
      divider={option.divider}>
        {option.label}<span className="context-sublabel">{option.subLabel}</span>
    </MenuItem>  
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ContextMenuTrigger id="list-item-context">
        <div className={"list-item-container" + (props.selected ? " list-item-selected" : "")}
          onClick={ () => props.onSelection(props.index) } >
          <p className="list-item-label">{props.name}</p>
        </div>
      </ContextMenuTrigger>
      <ContextMenu id="list-item-context">
        {contextOptions}
      </ContextMenu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've even gone as far as throwing print statements everywhere to ensure I wasn't somehow passing down a list of the same context menu info too. For instance at one point I wrote the map like so:

```
  const contextOptions = props.contextOptions.map((option) => {
    console.log(`Item: ${props.name}, label: ${option.label}, sub-label: ${option.subLabel}`);

    return (<MenuItem 
      key={option.label + option.subLabel} 
      disabled={option.disabled} 
      divider={option.divider}>
        {option.label}<span className="context-sublabel">{option.subLabel}</span>
    </MenuItem>);
  });
```

Output proved my data was correct:

```
Item: ITEM A, label: Copy "ITEM A", sub-label: 
Item: ITEM A, label: , sub-label: 
Item: ITEM A, label: Connect, sub-label:  - [PRIMARY IP A]
Item: ITEM A, label: Connect, sub-label:  - [BACKUP IP A]
Item: ITEM B, label: Copy "ITEM B", sub-label: 
Item: ITEM B, label: , sub-label: 
Item: ITEM B, label: Connect, sub-label:  - [PRIMARY IP B]
Item: ITEM B, label: Connect, sub-label:  - [BACKUP IP B]
Item: ITEM C, label: Copy "ITEM C", sub-label: 
Item: ITEM C, label: , sub-label: 
Item: ITEM C, label: Connect, sub-label:  - [PRIMARY IP C]
Item: ITEM C, label: Connect, sub-label:  - [BACKUP IP C]
```

Note: empty labels or sub-labels is fine in the context of my app.

I literally can't figure out why the UI actually getting rendered isn't showing the correct text. Perhaps it isn't supported? Every example I've seen of this library being used showed explicitly written out `MenuItem` JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

The `id` of each `ContextMenuTrigger` and `ContextMenu` must match, and they did. But since I was generating everything dynamically in a list, every element in my list used the same id, so they all displayed the same data. To make my ids unique, I appended the name prop to them, since in the context of my app the names are guaranteed to be unique:

```
return (
    <div>
      <ContextMenuTrigger id={"list-item-context" + `-${props.name}`}>
        <div className={"list-item-container" + (props.selected ? " list-item-selected" : "")}
          onClick={ () => props.onSelection(props.index) } >
          <p className="list-item-label">{props.name}</p>
        </div>
      </ContextMenuTrigger>
      <ContextMenu id={"list-item-context" + `-${props.name}`}>
        {contextOptions}
      </ContextMenu>
    </div>
  );
```